# textarea wont update to mysql database field PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, textarea

I am trying to update the contents of the User_Bio field in my Mysql Database, the update query works fine up until I add that in. it must be something to do with the textarea. I'm aware that I'm open to SQL injection using this method, but I have to code this website once, then recode it with security improvements, so I will be adding protection from that at a later date.(the database column names match up perfectly)

```
 $updateProfileQuery = "UPDATE users SET User_Firstname='" . $_POST['firstname'] . "', User_Surname='" . $_POST['surname'] . "', User_Bio='" . $_POST['bio'] . "' WHERE User_ID=" . $_SESSION['userid'];
    $saveUpdate = mysqli_query($dbc, $updateProfileQuery);

<h1><small>Bio:</small></h1>
                    <textarea form="post"  class="form-control" name="bio" id="bio">' . $row['User_Bio'] . '</textarea>
```

the form method is post and works fine up until the textarea is added into the SQL command.

Comment: textarea HTML element has  a form property, but it is not designed to contain a method, but the name of the form containing the textarea. The method should be specified in your HTML form tag! http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: sorry mis-read that, debug level one= `print_r($_POST);` check every thing is filled-in and labeled as expected

Comment: Please update with complete form. Looks like you have added text area a method property.

Comment: I appear to have fixed it, I added a form="*form name*" into the textarea tag, it didn't work straight away, but now it is, didn't change anything else though :/

Comment: that solution makes no sense, but if it  works ....

Comment: I was wrong, it was a comma, in the text area entry, I'm guessing its causing the SQL to fail, fixed now with encoding to html before posting to database, thanks anyway! :)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query. Your "solution" of encoding for HTML is completely, dangerously wrong. Placeholders will always escape your content correctly and you won't have insertion errors if you use them in a disciplined manner.

Comment: I'm aware of how at risk it is, but this website will never be hosted, its version 1.0 for a Uni assignment, our next assignment is build upon this website to protect and hopefully prevent our lecturer from implementing SQL injection, he specifically asked us not to for this assignment.

Comment: If you're not going to use placeholders, then you have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to escape the data, in case it contains quotes.

Comment: A comma in the text area shouldn't cause problems, but a quote would. Some people call them inverted commas, is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it was a single quote, I've been awake for over 24 hours now, my concept of reality is fading :D

Comment: @tadman outdated might be a better word than wrong. This method was pretty common once. It's still in tutorials out there in the wild. It's probably even in some books.

Comment: @TimOgilvy  Using `htmlspecialchars` on database data is completely wrong, it doesn't even come close to serving the function of escaping for the SQL context. Any books that recommend that need to be thrown in the fire and burned. There's a reason the [hall of shame](http://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/) is so big and a lack of proper escaping has claimed more than enough victims. Teaching people the dangerous way first is quite an irresponsible approach. It's like wearing safety glasses when using power tools. It's just common sense.

Comment: @tadman, not saying you are wrong, just that your wording is fairly confrontational. Shaming noobs is a bit harsh.

Comment: @TimOgilvy Sorry if it comes across that way, but a light shaming is a lot gentler than having your whole server hacked wide open because you made a simple mistake you didn't know was an issue.